# Android app doesn't remember what question was open

Tags: bug, android-app

In 1.0.60 when I leave the app and then relaunch it, the view defaults to Feed instead of returning to the same question.

Comment: A heisenbug. Sometimes I can, sometimes I cannot repro.

Comment: Wild guess: The OS runs out of memory and thus killing the apps, including SE. Not sure if it can be called as a bug (since it's the default behavior of Android app), but perhaps you can make it a [tag:feature-request] instead to always remember the last question, unless the user "close" the app explicitly.